# List Tables and Table Extended Properties

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, system-tables

I want to return a list of all tables within my database along with any related extended properties for the table.

This gives me the list of tables:

```
    SELECT TABLE_NAME AS tTableName, TABLE_TYPE AS tTableType
    FROM information_schema.tables AS t
    WHERE TABLE_TYPE = N'BASE TABLE'
    ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
```

This gives me the list of Extended Properties for Tables that have them:

```
    SELECT OBJECT_NAME(ep.major_id) AS [epTableName],
    CAST(ep.Value AS nvarchar(500)) AS [epExtendedProperty]
    FROM sys.extended_properties AS ep
    WHERE ep.name = N'MS_Description' AND ep.minor_id = 0
```

I cannot see how to combine these and preserve the WHERE conditions correctly. THis is wrong but it will give you insight as to where I went wrong:

```
    SELECT TABLE_NAME AS tTableName, TABLE_TYPE AS tTableType,
    OBJECT_NAME(ep.major_id) AS [epTableName],
    CAST(ep.Value AS nvarchar(500)) AS [epExtendedProperty]
    FROM information_schema.tables AS t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.extended_properties AS ep ON
    t.table_name= OBJECT_NAME(ep.major_id) 
    WHERE TABLE_TYPE = N'BASE TABLE'
    -- No clue where to put this: AND ep.name = N'MS_Description' AND ep.minor_id = 0
    ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
```

### Added from Joe's comment below Simon1979's answer...

```sql
SELECT 
    t.Table_Name, 
    q.epExtendedProperty 
FROM 
    information_schema.tables t 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   (SELECT 
        OBJECT_NAME(ep.major_id) epTableName, 
        CAST(ep.Value AS nvarchar(500)) AS epExtendedProperty 
    FROM 
        sys.extended_properties ep 
    WHERE 
        ep.name = N'MS_Description' AND 
        ep.minor_id = 0) q 
        ON  t.Table_Name = q.epTableName 
WHERE 
    t.Table_Type = N'BASE TABLE' AND 
    t.Table_Name <> 'sysdiagrams' 
ORDER BY 
    q.epExtendedProperty ASC, 
    t.Table_Name ASC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the below achieves what you want, though I don't have any extended properties on my tables that fit the criteria so it's hard to check if it works:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME AS tTableName, 
    TABLE_TYPE AS tTableType,
    q.epTableName,
    q.epExtendedProperty
FROM information_schema.tables AS t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT OBJECT_NAME(ep.major_id) AS [epTableName],
        CAST(ep.Value AS nvarchar(500)) AS [epExtendedProperty]
        FROM sys.extended_properties ep
        WHERE ep.name = N'MS_Description' AND ep.minor_id = 0) As q
    ON t.table_name = q.epTableName 
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = N'BASE TABLE'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: I cleaned up my original statement to the finished one below which works as I wanted it it to:
    'SELECT t.Table_Name,
    q.epExtendedProperty
    FROM information_schema.tables t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT OBJECT_NAME(ep.major_id) epTableName,
        CAST(ep.Value AS nvarchar(500)) AS epExtendedProperty
 FROM sys.extended_properties ep
 WHERE ep.name = N'MS_Description' AND ep.minor_id = 0) q
    ON t.Table_Name = q.epTableName
WHERE t.Table_Type = N'BASE TABLE' AND t.Table_Name <> 'sysdiagrams'
ORDER BY q.epExtendedProperty ASC, t.Table_Name ASC'